# How to refer VHD in a storage account blob container - Imagereference Id

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

```
{
         "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
         "name": "[parameters('vaultVMName')]",
         "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
         "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
         "zones": [
            "[parameters('availabilityZone')]"
         ],
         "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned"
         },
         "properties": {
            "storageProfile": {
               "imageReference":{
                  "id":"<How to pass id of a VHD stored in azure  blob container>"
               },
               "osDisk":{
                  "createOption":"FromImage",
                  "managedDisk":{
                     "storageAccountType":"Premium_LRS"
                  }
               }
            },
            "networkProfile": {
               "networkInterfaces": [
                  {
                     "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
```

This is for Azure virtual machine  ARM template using VHD. How to refer VHD in a blob storage  in imageReference id for the creation of virtual machine OSDisk ?

Comment: Did you try with the blob URL from your storage account?

Comment: its  doesn't work with URL of the blob , i think it requires resourceId of  the blob  - Any idea ?

Comment: Ok so that parameter where you're trying to put the ID, the`imageReference`, can only be used for a managed image ID. There's no way you'll get it working with the VHD blob URL For blob, you should instead try to look at the following under OsDisk block  `"name": "string",
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "string"
        }` 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2018-10-01/virtualmachines?tabs=json#VirtualHardDisk

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @KedMardemootoo I created an image  from vhd and referenced it and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Ked, the attribute [`imageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?tabs=json#storageprofile-object) is only available for the managed disk. It means you will create an extra managed OS disk from the images in the Azure MarketPlace. But for the VHD file in the storage account, it's not the way that creates a copy from the VHD file, it attaches the VHD file as an unmanaged OS disk to the VM. So use the attribute [`vhd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?tabs=json#virtualharddisk-object) and it will find the VHD file and attach it.